# Chart.js Bar Chart change width (not duplicated to bar width questions!)

Tags: chart.js

How can I change the bar width? I mean, the width from the bar I could change, but not this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The bar width is influenced through the options [`barPercentage` and `categoryPercentage`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-configuration), which both need to be defined on the `dataset`.

To find out about the relationship between `barPercentage` and `categoryPercentage`, see [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#barpercentage-vs-categorypercentage).

In case you simply want to see the existing bars closer to each other, you need to change the height of the chart. This can be done directly on the `canvas` as follows:

```
<canvas id="canvas" height="40"></canvas>
```

Please have a look at the following code snippet.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('canvas'), {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'data',
      data: [15, 8],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    title: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="40"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is not helpful. I need to scale down the sample width. But scaling down both percentages you just mentioned results not in a smaller 'blank' space of the sample width.
```
// categoryPercentage: 0.5
// barPercentage: 1.0
Bar:            |1.||1.|
Category:       |  .5  |
Sample:     |==============|
```
but I want sample smaller

Comment: @Prutheus: unfortunately I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you see the red marked areas? how to shrink them - not the blue bar width, this should be so small like I have it already. now, every line (column) just needs to be closer together.

Comment: the solution on this is hard-coding the height: but this is not possible for me.